# Can I filter Github issues using parameters multiple times?

Tags: github, github-issues

I am looking for a way to build a filter like:

Reviewed by me but not reviewed by user xyz

I know I can do a OR search for labels but I cant find anything for other properties.

What I expected to work was

```
is:open is:pr reviewed-by:@me -reviewed-by:xyz
```

1. Is it possible to do something like this?
2. If not, is it possible to
   export all issues to an excel sheet so I can filter it there?

Answer (score 0):

A [2020 answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/142071) states:

> The GitHub global search (top-left bar on any page on https://github.com) seems to have an implicit `AND` between all search fields, and an implicit `OR` between fields you reuse:

So:

`is:open is:pr reviewed-by:@me -reviewed-by:xyz`

should act as:

`is:open AND is:pr AND (reviewed-by:@me OR -reviewed-by:xyz)`

Which might not be what you want.

Comment: Yes, thats not what I want. Isn't there some kind of "advanced query" where I can put the operators in myself?

Comment: @SimonBalling Not that I know of. Explicit operators don't seem to be supported.